# Select many checkbox selected items return null when there is nested ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, uirepeat, selectmanycheckbox

I have a problem list. Each problem has a sub category and main category and also each sub category has a main category. I want to list the problems like above.

--Main category1 (1 is id)
  ----subcat1
    ------problem1
    ------problem2
  ----subcat2
    ------problem3

--main category2
    ----subcat3
    ------problem4
    ------problem5
  ----subcat4
    ------problem6

and so on.

The html part is here;

```
    <ui:repeat  var="mainCatvar" value="#{dprEdit.mainCategories}">
    <h:outputText value="#{mainCatvar.mainCatName}" styleClass="mainTitle" /><br></br>  
            <ui:repeat var="subCategory" value="#{mainCatvar.subCategories}">
            <h:outputText value="#{subCategory.subCatName}" styleClass="title" />
                <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{dprEdit.selectedProblems}"  >
                <f:selectItems value="#{subCategory.problems}" var="problem" 
                itemValue="#{problem.problemName}" itemLabel="#{problem.problemName}" />                                    
                </h:selectManyCheckbox>
            </ui:repeat>
    </ui:repeat>
<p:commandButton action="#{dprCreate.save}" value="Save" update="form1" ajax="false" style="width:150px" />
```

Here is my backend code;

```
    public class MainCatDAO extends BaseDAO {   
        private final static String SELECT_ALL_MAIN_CATEGORIES ="SELECT * FROM TESTAE.MAINCATPF";
        public MainCatDAO(Connection connection) {      
            super(connection);
        }
        private List<MainCat> getTable(String query, Object... values) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            List<MainCat> table = new ArrayList<MainCat>();
            List<Map<String, Object>> data = this.getData(query, values);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                ArrayList<SubCat> subList = new ArrayList<SubCat>();    
                // subList'i tekrardan tanımlama yani clear etmeme sebebim; maincat'a subList'i set etmeme rağmen,
                //sonrasında subList'i clear edince maincat'ın subList'i de sıfırlanıyor. 
                //Bu yüzden subList'i her seferinde tekrar tanımlıyorum.
                Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                MainCat maincat = new MainCat();
                row = data.get(i);
                maincat.setMainCatId(((BigDecimal) row.get("MAINCATID")).intValue());
                maincat.setMainCatName(((String) row.get("MAINCATNAM")).trim());

                String sorgu = "SELECT * FROM TESTAE.SUBCATPF WHERE MAINCATID='"+((BigDecimal) row.get("MAINCATID")).intValue()+"'";            

                List<Map<String, Object>> dataSub = this.getData(sorgu);
                for (int a = 0; a < dataSub.size(); a++) {
                    ArrayList<Problem> problemList = new ArrayList<Problem>();
                    SubCat subcat = new SubCat();
                    row = dataSub.get(a);
                    if (row.get("SUBCATNAME") == null)
                        subcat.setSubCatName("");   
                    else
                        subcat.setSubCatName((((String) row.get("SUBCATNAME")).trim()));
                    subList.add(subcat);

                    String sorgu2 = "SELECT * FROM TESTAE.PROBLEMPF WHERE SUBCATID='"+((BigDecimal) row.get("SUBCATID")).intValue()+"'";
                    List<Map<String, Object>> dataProb = this.getData(sorgu2);
                    for (int p = 0; p < dataProb.size(); p++) {
                        Problem problem = new Problem();
                        row = dataProb.get(p);
                        Integer problemId = ((BigDecimal) row.get("PROBLEMID")).intValue();

                        if (row.get("PRBLMNAME") == null)
                            problem.setProblemName("");
                        else
                            problem.setProblemName((((String) row.get("PRBLMNAME")).trim()));
                        problemList.add(problem);
                    }
                    subcat.setProblems(problemList);
                }
                maincat.setSubCategories(subList);
                table.add(maincat);
            }
            return table;
        }

        public List<MainCat> getmainCategories () throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

            return getTable(SELECT_ALL_MAIN_CATEGORIES);
    }}


Here is my save function;

            @ManagedBean(name = "dprEdit")
            @ViewScoped
            public class DprEdit implements Serializable {
            private List<String> selectedProblems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<MainCat> mainCategories;
    public DprEdit() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    mainCategories = new MainCatDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection()).getmainCategories();}

            public String save() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ParseException {
                    DprDAO dprDAO = new DprDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection());


                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedProblems.size(); i++) {
                        dpr.setFormId(dpr.getFormId());
                        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        Date today = new Date();
                        formDate = formatter.parse(formatter.format(today));
                    dpr.setFormDate(formDate);
                    dpr.setFilledBy(username);
                    dpr.setProblemName(selectedProblems.get(i));
                    String problemName = selectedProblems.get(i);
                    ProblemDAO problemDAO = new ProblemDAO(ConnectionManager.getConnection());
                    Problem prob = problemDAO.getProblemId(problemName);
                    dpr.setProblemId(prob.getProblemId());
                        dprDAO.insertDetail(dpr);
                    }
            public List<String> getSelectedProblems() {
                    return selectedProblems;
                }

            public void setSelectedProblems(List<String> selectedProblems) {
                    this.selectedProblems = selectedProblems;
                }
    public Integer getMaincatid() {
            return maincatid;
        }

        public void setMaincatid(Integer maincatid) {
            this.maincatid = maincatid;
        }}
```

My problem model attributes;

```
private Integer problemId;
private String problemName;
private String subCategory;
private String mainCategory;
```

my subcategory model attributes;

```
private Integer subCatId;
private String subCatName;
private List<Problem> problems;
```

my main category model attributes;

```
private Integer mainCatId;
private String mainCatName;
private List<SubCat> subCategories;
```

So, the problem is that I click some problems on the list then I click the save button and I expect to that selectedProblem list is full of my clicked problems. However the selectedProblems list is empty!

Do you have any advice?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closer at `<h:selectManyCheckbox value>`, particularly at the associated bean.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{dprEdit.mainCategories}" var="mainCatvar">
    <ui:repeat value="#{mainCatvar.subCategories}" var="subCategory">
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{dprEdit.selectedProblems}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{subCategory.problems}" />
```

Basically, you're binding the selected values of **all** checkbox groups to **one and same** bean property. During processing the form submit, every iteration will override the submitted values of checkbox group of the previous iteration. If you've placed a debug breakpoint on the `setSelectedProblems()` setter, you'd have noticed that. This way you ultimately end up with the submitted values of the **last** checkbox group. Given the "return null" complaint, apparently you selected nothing there.

This is definitely wrong. The `<h:selectManyCheckbox value>` should in some way be associated with the currently iterated `#{subCategory}`, not directly with the `#{dprEdit}` managed bean. One way is mapping it with `#{subCategory}` as key:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{dprEdit.selectedProblems[subCategory]}">
```

With:

```
private Map<SubCat, String[]> selectedProblems = new HashMap<>();
```

Note that you can't use `List<String>` here as generic type information is erased during runtime and the default model value is `String[]` and there's no way of instructing JSF/EL otherwise. If you want to use a fixed type, you could consider moving the `selectedProblems` into `SubCat` so that you can keep using `List<String>`:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{subCategory.selectedProblems}">
```

Comment: Something has been changed thank you but it doesn't work correctly. selectedProblem.size() is always 15 which is the number of subcategories. There is a point that I cannot understand. I want to have a selectedProblem list like this ['problemname1', 'problemname2',....] but now my selectedProblem looks like ['subcat1', 'subcat2',....] I have a selectedProblem list  So, is it okay to use SubCat model in Hashmap?

Comment: Are you new to Java maps? The selected problems are just available as map value associated with subcategory as map key. Iterate over `selectedProblems.entrySet()` or `selectedOProblems.values()` to get them all (the latter however doesn't allow you to associate them with a subcategory while saving in the DB, nor did your initial approach ...).

Comment: Sorry I could not explain  correctly. Yes I have a map. The key of the map is a subcategory and the value of it is a list which consist of String. When I iterate it I can get all subcategories  and its problems. But I want the selected ones (problems). By the way, yes I am new to Java map :)

Comment: Hm? The selected ones are in that map. That "its problems" are the selected ones.

Comment: No. Something goes wrong. Selected item is full of all subcategories. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, sure all map keys are filled. There's otherwise no way to find selected problems for each subcategory. Those keys do not represent selected problems. I am talking about map values. The selected problems are set as `List<String>` map value associated with subcategory. You should explore the contents of that `List<String>` for each subcategory.

Comment: I missed something I am sorry. Thank you. You are right. I can reach the selected problems on the way you told. However, still I have a problem. Each item of selectedProblems.enrtySet() is entry and when I try to get value of entry, I use entry.getValue(). I suppose its type is a List<String> but I get error which is "[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.List".  I can not figure casting out. I can not find any useful information about casting hasmap. Could you help me?

Comment: Right, the eternal EL+Erasure problem, I should know better. I fixed the answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you but I pass the itemValue "problemName" but my values come like this  "com.myproject.srm.model.Problem@2df0f8d3". How can I get my problems' name?

Comment: Use `<f:selectItems itemLabel>` the way you did. My answer just contains the minimal snippet needed to solve the problem as described in the question.

Comment: Okey I will figure out. Thank you very much!